# Wrap a div into wrapper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a div with some elements inside it. What I want is to create a wrapper div around that div using j query.

```
<div id="foo">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button">
</div>
```

I need to make the above code look like the following

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="foo">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="button">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method.

```js
$( "#foo" ).wrap( "<div class='wrapper'></div>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
<input type="text">
<input type="button">
</div>
```